# .NET 6 SDK is shipped with the old Nuget packages

Tags: .net, linux, docker, security, nuget

I'm building a Docker image based on Almalinux 8.6. For running my application I need the .NET SDK 6 which is installed by running `dnf install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0`.  After that I'm running the Trivy security scan (https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy) upon the image.
The `dnf list *dotnet*` says the following packages are installed then:

```
Installed Packages

dotnet-apphost-pack-6.0.x86_64        6.0.10-1.el8_6
dotnet-host.x86_64                    6.0.10-1.el8_6                                                                            
dotnet-hostfxr-6.0.x86_64             6.0.10-1.el8_6                                                                            
dotnet-runtime-6.0.x86_64             6.0.10-1.el8_6                                                                            
dotnet-sdk-6.0.x86_64                 6.0.110-1.el8_6                                                                           
dotnet-targeting-pack-6.0.x86_64      6.0.10-1.el8_6                                                                      
dotnet-templates-6.0.x86_64           6.0.110-1.el8_6
```

Trivy reports there are really old and vulnerable nuget packages that are shipped with .NET SDK (the JSON files that summarize the deps are placed under the SDK path).

**Is there any way to get rid of or update these old packages?**

Below is the security scan report (it was shrinked a bit to fit into the textbox here):

```
<Docker image tag> (alma 8.6)
=====================================================================================
Total: 0 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 0, HIGH: 0, CRITICAL: 0)

usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/DotnetTools/dotnet-format/dotnet-format.deps.json (dotnet-core)
============================================================================================
Total: 3 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 1, HIGH: 1, CRITICAL: 1)

┌────────────────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│            Library             │ Vulnerability  │ Severity │ Installed Version │ Fixed Version │                           Title                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Drawing.Common          │ CVE-2021-24112 │ CRITICAL │ 4.7.0             │ 5.0.3, 4.7.2  │ dotnet: Remote Code Execution Vulnerability               │
│                                │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2021-24112                │
├────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Net.Http                │ CVE-2018-8292  │ HIGH     │ 4.3.0             │ 4.3.4         │ .NET Core: information disclosure due to authentication   │
│                                │                │          │                   │               │ information exposed in a redirect...                      │
│                                │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2018-8292                 │
├────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┤                   ├───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Text.RegularExpressions │ CVE-2019-0820  │ MEDIUM   │                   │ 4.3.1         │ dotnet: timeouts for regular expressions are not enforced │
│                                │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2019-0820                 │
└────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/DotnetTools/dotnet-watch/6.0.110-servicing.22476.46/tools/net6.0/any/dotnet-watch.deps.json (dotnet-core)
======================================================================================================================================
Total: 3 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 1, HIGH: 1, CRITICAL: 1)

┌────────────────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│            Library             │ Vulnerability  │ Severity │ Installed Version │ Fixed Version │                           Title                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Drawing.Common          │ CVE-2021-24112 │ CRITICAL │ 4.7.0             │ 5.0.3, 4.7.2  │ dotnet: Remote Code Execution Vulnerability               │
│                                │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2021-24112                │
├────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Net.Http                │ CVE-2018-8292  │ HIGH     │ 4.3.0             │ 4.3.4         │ .NET Core: information disclosure due to authentication   │
│                                │                │          │                   │               │ information exposed in a redirect...                      │
│                                │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2018-8292                 │
├────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┤                   ├───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Text.RegularExpressions │ CVE-2019-0820  │ MEDIUM   │                   │ 4.3.1         │ dotnet: timeouts for regular expressions are not enforced │
│                                │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2019-0820                 │
└────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/FSharp/fsc.deps.json (dotnet-core)
===============================================================
Total: 3 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 1, HIGH: 1, CRITICAL: 1)

┌──────────────────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│             Library              │ Vulnerability  │ Severity │ Installed Version │ Fixed Version │                          Title                          │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Drawing.Common            │ CVE-2021-24112 │ CRITICAL │ 4.7.0             │ 5.0.3, 4.7.2  │ dotnet: Remote Code Execution Vulnerability             │
│                                  │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2021-24112              │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Net.Http                  │ CVE-2018-8292  │ HIGH     │ 4.3.0             │ 4.3.4         │ .NET Core: information disclosure due to authentication │
│                                  │                │          │                   │               │ information exposed in a redirect...                    │
│                                  │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2018-8292               │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Security.Cryptography.Xml │ CVE-2022-34716 │ MEDIUM   │ 4.7.0             │ 6.0.1, 4.7.1  │ dotnet: External Entity Injection during XML signature  │
│                                  │                │          │                   │               │ verification                                            │
│                                  │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2022-34716              │
└──────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/FSharp/fsi.deps.json (dotnet-core)
===============================================================
Total: 3 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 1, HIGH: 1, CRITICAL: 1)

┌──────────────────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│             Library              │ Vulnerability  │ Severity │ Installed Version │ Fixed Version │                          Title                          │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Drawing.Common            │ CVE-2021-24112 │ CRITICAL │ 4.7.0             │ 5.0.3, 4.7.2  │ dotnet: Remote Code Execution Vulnerability             │
│                                  │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2021-24112              │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Net.Http                  │ CVE-2018-8292  │ HIGH     │ 4.3.0             │ 4.3.4         │ .NET Core: information disclosure due to authentication │
│                                  │                │          │                   │               │ information exposed in a redirect...                    │
│                                  │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2018-8292               │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Security.Cryptography.Xml │ CVE-2022-34716 │ MEDIUM   │ 4.7.0             │ 6.0.1, 4.7.1  │ dotnet: External Entity Injection during XML signature  │
│                                  │                │          │                   │               │ verification                                            │
│                                  │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2022-34716              │
└──────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/MSBuild.deps.json (dotnet-core)
============================================================
Total: 5 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 2, HIGH: 2, CRITICAL: 1)

┌──────────────────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│             Library              │ Vulnerability  │ Severity │ Installed Version │                  Fixed Version                   │                           Title                           │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ NuGet.Commands                   │ CVE-2022-41032 │ HIGH     │ 6.0.3-rc.32767    │ 6.3.1, 6.2.2, 6.0.3, 5.11.3, 5.9.3, 5.7.3, 4.9.6 │ dotnet: Nuget cache poisoning on Linux via world-writable │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ cache directory                                           │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2022-41032                │
├──────────────────────────────────┤                │          │                   │                                                  │                                                           │
│ NuGet.Protocol                   │                │          │                   │                                                  │                                                           │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Drawing.Common            │ CVE-2021-24112 │ CRITICAL │ 4.7.0             │ 5.0.3, 4.7.2                                     │ dotnet: Remote Code Execution Vulnerability               │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2021-24112                │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┤                   ├──────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Security.Cryptography.Xml │ CVE-2022-34716 │ MEDIUM   │                   │ 6.0.1, 4.7.1                                     │ dotnet: External Entity Injection during XML signature    │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ verification                                              │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2022-34716                │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┤          ├───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Text.RegularExpressions   │ CVE-2019-0820  │          │ 4.3.0             │ 4.3.1                                            │ dotnet: timeouts for regular expressions are not enforced │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2019-0820                 │
└──────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/NuGet.CommandLine.XPlat.deps.json (dotnet-core)
============================================================================
Total: 5 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 2, HIGH: 2, CRITICAL: 1)

┌──────────────────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│             Library              │ Vulnerability  │ Severity │ Installed Version │                  Fixed Version                   │                           Title                           │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ NuGet.Commands                   │ CVE-2022-41032 │ HIGH     │ 6.0.3-rc.32767    │ 6.3.1, 6.2.2, 6.0.3, 5.11.3, 5.9.3, 5.7.3, 4.9.6 │ dotnet: Nuget cache poisoning on Linux via world-writable │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ cache directory                                           │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2022-41032                │
├──────────────────────────────────┤                │          │                   │                                                  │                                                           │
│ NuGet.Protocol                   │                │          │                   │                                                  │                                                           │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Drawing.Common            │ CVE-2021-24112 │ CRITICAL │ 4.7.0             │ 5.0.3, 4.7.2                                     │ dotnet: Remote Code Execution Vulnerability               │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2021-24112                │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┤                   ├──────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Security.Cryptography.Xml │ CVE-2022-34716 │ MEDIUM   │                   │ 6.0.1, 4.7.1                                     │ dotnet: External Entity Injection during XML signature    │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ verification                                              │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2022-34716                │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┤          ├───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Text.RegularExpressions   │ CVE-2019-0820  │          │ 4.3.0             │ 4.3.1                                            │ dotnet: timeouts for regular expressions are not enforced │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2019-0820                 │
└──────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks/tools/net6.0/ILLink.Tasks.deps.json (dotnet-core)
==============================================================================================================
Total: 1 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 0, HIGH: 0, CRITICAL: 1)

┌───────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│        Library        │ Vulnerability  │ Severity │ Installed Version │ Fixed Version │                    Title                    │
├───────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Drawing.Common │ CVE-2021-24112 │ CRITICAL │ 4.7.0             │ 5.0.3, 4.7.2  │ dotnet: Remote Code Execution Vulnerability │
│                       │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2021-24112  │
└───────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────┘

usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/dotnet-watch.deps.json (dotnet-core)
=================================================================
Total: 3 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 1, HIGH: 1, CRITICAL: 1)

┌────────────────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│            Library             │ Vulnerability  │ Severity │ Installed Version │ Fixed Version │                           Title                           │
├────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Drawing.Common          │ CVE-2021-24112 │ CRITICAL │ 4.7.0             │ 5.0.3, 4.7.2  │ dotnet: Remote Code Execution Vulnerability               │
│                                │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2021-24112                │
├────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Net.Http                │ CVE-2018-8292  │ HIGH     │ 4.3.0             │ 4.3.4         │ .NET Core: information disclosure due to authentication   │
│                                │                │          │                   │               │ information exposed in a redirect...                      │
│                                │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2018-8292                 │
├────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┤                   ├───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Text.RegularExpressions │ CVE-2019-0820  │ MEDIUM   │                   │ 4.3.1         │ dotnet: timeouts for regular expressions are not enforced │
│                                │                │          │                   │               │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2019-0820                 │
└────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/dotnet.deps.json (dotnet-core)
===========================================================
Total: 5 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 2, HIGH: 2, CRITICAL: 1)

┌──────────────────────────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│             Library              │ Vulnerability  │ Severity │ Installed Version │                  Fixed Version                   │                           Title                           │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ NuGet.Commands                   │ CVE-2022-41032 │ HIGH     │ 6.0.3-rc.32767    │ 6.3.1, 6.2.2, 6.0.3, 5.11.3, 5.9.3, 5.7.3, 4.9.6 │ dotnet: Nuget cache poisoning on Linux via world-writable │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ cache directory                                           │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2022-41032                │
├──────────────────────────────────┤                │          │                   │                                                  │                                                           │
│ NuGet.Protocol                   │                │          │                   │                                                  │                                                           │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Drawing.Common            │ CVE-2021-24112 │ CRITICAL │ 4.7.0             │ 5.0.3, 4.7.2                                     │ dotnet: Remote Code Execution Vulnerability               │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2021-24112                │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┤                   ├──────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Security.Cryptography.Xml │ CVE-2022-34716 │ MEDIUM   │                   │ 6.0.1, 4.7.1                                     │ dotnet: External Entity Injection during XML signature    │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ verification                                              │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2022-34716                │
├──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┤          ├───────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ System.Text.RegularExpressions   │ CVE-2019-0820  │          │ 4.3.0             │ 4.3.1                                            │ dotnet: timeouts for regular expressions are not enforced │
│                                  │                │          │                   │                                                  │ https://avd.aquasec.com/nvd/cve-2019-0820                 │
└──────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/package.deps.json (dotnet-core)
usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/vstest.console.deps.json (dotnet-core)
usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/testhost.deps.json (dotnet-core)
usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/testhost.x86.deps.json (dotnet-core)
usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/datacollector.deps.json (dotnet-core)
usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/TestHost/testhost.deps.json (dotnet-core)
usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/6.0.110/TestHost/testhost.x86.deps.json (dotnet-core)
======================================================================
Total: 1 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 0, HIGH: 1, CRITICAL: 0)

┌─────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│     Library     │    Vulnerability    │ Severity │ Installed Version │ Fixed Version │                       Title                       │
├─────────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Newtonsoft.Json │ GHSA-5crp-9r3c-p9vr │ HIGH     │ 9.0.1             │ 13.0.1        │ Improper Handling of Exceptional Conditions in    │
│                 │                     │          │                   │               │ Newtonsoft.Json                                   │
│                 │                     │          │                   │               │ https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5crp-9r3c-p9vr │
└─────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I tried installing the up-to-date version of these packages manually but the package installation is .NET project/solution-specific and is not reflected on the SDK path, so the report is obviously the same then.

Comment: Is there a reason your application needs the SDK rather than just a runtime to run?

Comment: Seems like AlmaLinux needs to update their packages to newer versions.

Comment: Did You solve this ? I facing a similar issue, but using a regular net 6 Api with checkMark scan

Comment: Yep, switched to the runtime and all the vulnerabilities were gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to .NET runtime solved the issue